# Unity - Multiple-display (IPad + Monitor)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, ipad

I'm developing an app in Unity for the ios platform.
I need to see in the IPad in one way and in the monitor / TV to see in another way, that is, 2 cameras pointing to different areas that communicate with each other through the scripts.

I have been looking at the documentation and it says that the option of several displays is available only for desktop apps (Windows, Linux, Mac).

My question is:

Is there any way to achieve it in 2 different ways on 2 devices with different screen sizes?

Thank you,

Comment: Actually you don't need two different cameras in your scene. You need just to set a different camera settings for each device, right? Is that your goal?

Comment: Yes, but the app has to be the same for the 2 platforms and different things are seen on each device.

Comment: If I correctly understood your need: you need a single view of your scene on each device. And you need some devices to show a different perspective of your scene. I don't think you actually need multi-display... you just have to write a script for setting your main camera differently, and maybe enable / disable a few game objects depending on your device type. So you actually don't need a different app, neither multi-view. See: https://answers.unity.com/questions/63221/how-to-set-main-camera.html

Comment: Basically what I need is to manage the app from the ipad and that the changes will be seen on the monitor / TV.
I need that while I have a menu with the different options, on the TV a video is played explaining different things, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should consider the following:

I'd suggest making three scenes. One scene you decorate for your Monitor, the other for your Ipad. 
The other scene will be your "start" scene. In this scene, create an empty gameobject and create and attach the following script.

```
public class ApplicationManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Awake()
    {
        if(SystemInfo.deviceModel.Contains("iPad"))
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
        }
        else
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
        }
    }
}
```

That way, if you start the app on any ipad, it will load the Ipad scene (as long as the scene is marked with index 2 in your build index)

Comment: I would like that the same scene will be played in 2 devices same time.

Comment: Than you have to define the changes between the two devices in the if/ else statement instead of the loadscene. E.g. Move the camera position or show/ hide certain UI elements